# "Bios Not fully ACPI compatible"

Tags: bios, bsod, acpi

Why would a computer that has been working for month's suddenly start having a "Bios not fully ACPI compatible" blue screen error, when the bios has not changed?

Comment: not a complete answer, but the situation you describe may be a sign of hardware failure. backup data now if possible.

Comment: @quack Thanks, I'm leaning towards it being some memory going bad.

Comment: @C.Ross: try running *memtest86+* (via Ubuntu LiveCD if you need to get it)

Comment: @quack That's the plan.  Explaining iso's and live cd's over the phone is no fun though.

Comment: @CRoss: no.  go ahead, it's all yours if you care to write it up.

Comment: similar question, different answer - http://superuser.com/questions/1005972/error-with-winpe-the-bios-in-this-system-is-not-fully-acpi-compliant

Answer (score 2):

During testing with Windows memory tool, the problem occurred.

After contacting DELL support they gave permission to open the case and re-seat the memory, which was done.

This corrected the issue.