# BIOS not ACPI compliant, on windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, bios, acpi

I was facing a problem of blank screen with cursor after login in my Lenovo G40-30 laptop which was pre-installed with windows 8. So to resolve it I somehow decided to change it from UEFI boot to legacy boot  After that I am not able to access boot options from any key F2/F12. Then I tried to install windows 7 from a bootable usb pen drive, which I created from Rufus software with option 'Partition Scheme and Target System type' set as  'MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI'. The laptop now boots with pen drive, and starts installing windows, but shows error BIOS not fully ACPI compliant, with error code 0x000000A5. Why I am getting this error, and how to resolve it?

Comment: Why did you switch exactly?  Windows 7 supports UEFI and GPT.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Bios Not fully ACPI compatible"](http://superuser.com/questions/138076/bios-not-fully-acpi-compatible)

Comment: You changed "from UEFI to Legacy" but you're "not able to access [the] BIOS"? You changed to Legacy but are installing UEFI? I have no clue what you're asking or what you've done. Consider revision seeing as how I'm unable to edit for you giving the lack of clarity. Why can't you access the BIOS? What model of Lenovo Laptop? What kind of Win7/Win8?

Answer (score 2):

Got my answer at lenovo official website. BIOS needed to be updated. 
http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht100535