# How do I install an operating system for skylake processor?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-installer, intel-core-i5

I've recently purchased i5-6600k and assembled it into an MSI H110 PRO-VH PLUS motherboard.

My problem is, I am not able to install an operating system. I've tried Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 16.10, Windows 7, 10, and even OS X! Ubuntu gets stuck, Windows installation gets stuck, OS X gets stuck.

All for different reasons I suppose.

**Ubuntu:**

```
... some logs
HSET not enabled!
... few more lines
```

or when I use `nomodeset`

```
... some logs
Intel P-state driver initializing
```

**Windows:**

Simply gets stuck on the first screen of the installation process - spinning dots with windows logs. I've waited for more than 20 minutes with out any change.

**OS X:**

Best to forget it, I think. I am happy if I can get Ubuntu running on the box.

Comment: OS X gets stuck? To my knowledge OS X returns an error message saying it can only be installed on a Mac. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try adding "i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 nouveau.blacklist=1 edd=on nolapic pcie_aspm=force tpm_tis.interrupts=0" when you boot Ubuntu to see if that works.    You might also want to try an alternative distro like Mint.

Comment: @FleetCommand I followed [this](http://lifehacker.com/the-always-up-to-date-guide-to-building-a-hackintosh-o-5841604) for mac check it out.

Comment: @davidgo i tried i915.preliminary_hw_support but not the other flags.. will try them now. Also, regarding Mint, isn't it also based on ubuntu and will have the same problems? That's why I hadn't tried it. But will give it a shot anyway.

Comment: With respect of Mint, don't know.  I  know I've had some systems where Mint booted no problem where Ubuntu did not, and vice-versa. Mint is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: do you use BIOS/CMS or UEFI boot? Win7 stucks here in UEFI mode when GOP s activated: http://superuser.com/a/1057484/174557

Comment: also tried ubuntu 17.04 beta, mint, elementary os, hiren's boot cd. nothing worked. plugged in an old geforce 210 graphic card i had and was able to install os x sierra. i am guess this is something to do with hd 530 graphics support?